# A definite integral identity

Tags: integration

While reading a physics paper, I encountered the following identity:
$$ \int_{0}^\infty t^p \cos(Lat) \,e^{-Lbt} \mathrm{d}t = (-1)^{p+1} \frac{p!}{L\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos{((p+1)\alpha)},  $$
where $\alpha = \arctan\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)$ and $a,b,p,L$ are real constants, $b,L>0$. However, I don't know how to prove this, I'm at loss even for a starting point. Could someone give a hint for how to prove this?

Comment: replace $\cos$ with its expression of exponentials, then you get something like the $\Gamma$ function. By the way, what is the $M$ here?

Comment: Thanks, that may be the way to start. $M$ was $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $p>-1$ and $b,L>0$ to ensure convergence, your integral is the real part of 
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}t^p e^{-L(b-ia)t}\,dt =\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{L^{p+1}(b-ia)^{p+1}}$$
and to compute the real part of $\frac{1}{(b-ia)^{p+1}}$ is not a difficult task.